# INVALID_IMAGE_OPTIMIZE_REQUEST error with NextJS on production with Vercel

Tags: amazon-s3, next.js, vercel

When I execute from my production server, one of my requests to retrieve a photo fails with a 400: BAD_REQUEST error. Code: INVALID_IMAGE_OPTIMIZE_REQUEST when I try to fetch an image from my production S3.

In staging, the request successfully retrieves this image on the production S3, and production is able to retrieve an image from the staging S3. Here is my next.config.js file.

```
module.exports = {
 ...
  reactStrictMode: true,
  images: {
    domains: [
      "localhost",
      "xxfiles-prod.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com",
      "xxfiles-staging.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com",
    ],
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution that currently works and that I've found was to remove the optimization by adding this prop
`unoptimized={true}` to my `<Image />` that wasn't displaying.

I'm open to hearing if you have a better solution to keep the optimization.